# c++ how to allocate memory an array like T* var[1]

Tags: c++, arrays

The size of the pointer array is known. How do i allocate memory to `T* var[1]`?

I tried:

```
T* var[1];
var = new T*[count];
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) 
  var[i] = new T;
```

but the compiler states: "cannot convert from T ** to T*[1]"

Comment: You don't need to allocate memory for `var`. You just need to make its sole element point to a valid `T` object.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` ?

Comment: i can't change the type of the variable .. so vector is not an option, the variable should be a twodimensional array .. with n pointers pointing to different pointers of T

Comment: declaration: T* var[1];

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `var` was declared as `T**`, your code [works perfectly fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3733cb5144630506). I would highly recommend you to use `std::vector` as:

```
std::vector<T> var(count);
```

though.

---

Apparently the declaration is in the form:

```
T* var[1];
```

This is a statically allocated array of pointers. You will have to use:

```
var[0] = new T;
```

to fill it up.

For example you could have:

```
constexpr int count = 3;
T* var[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    var[i] = new T;
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c61180df9e7bd8a1)

Comment: i can't change the type of the variable .. so vector is not an option

Comment: but where are the pointers to T* stored? this only works for p[0] but not for an array of pointers.

Comment: @Christian They are stored on the stack. And it's effectively an array of pointers (of 1 element apparently). And no, this works for any number of pointers. You said that you cannot change the type of the variable, that's what you get.

Comment: In what sense do you expect the stack to be "lost"?

Answer (score 0):

```
T** var = new T*[count];
...
delete[] var;
```

---

The current type (T*)[1] is equivalent to T**, but a clever compiler might impose a warning if there is more than one element in the corresponing dimension.

If it is a member of a struct, then there is an array of only one pointer, maybe some onedimensional T array:

```
var[0][i]
```

Comment: @Christian I'm curious. Why wouldn't you be able to change the type of the variable? Because if you can't then you have an array of 1 element. You might as well just use a single pointer (`T* var = ...`), or even better `T var(...);`.

Comment: the variable is used in a piece of code which i can't change .. its a member of a struct .. the variable is a an array of pointers where each pointer redirects to another pointer of type T.

So for example  T* p = var[0][0];

Comment: @Christian That message makes no sense to me.

Comment: Listen, forget about pointers, and use `std::vector` for a dynamic array and `std::array` if you want a static array. This is especially true for "`struct`s". `new`, C-style arrays and `delete` are very advanced topics.

Comment: sorry, i mean T p = var[0][0];

Comment: @Christian "the variable is a an array of pointers where each pointer redirects to another pointer of type T." No, it is not. as has been pointer out to you repeatedly, it is an array of pointers with a *single element*. It is fundamentally useless.

Comment: @ juanchopanza, at runtime the variable contains an array of n pointers. each entry is a pointer to an instance of T. i just want to make a deep copy of it...